# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison with djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I am trying to make an app with django using djongo and mongodb. The connectivity for tables with no foreign key is working fine but where there is a Foreign Key involved, it is throwing this error. I will be greatful if anyone could help. I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Users\theri\Desktop\Python_Amygo\amygo_python\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 808, in **iter**
yield from iter(self._query)

File "C:\Users\theri\Desktop\Python_Amygo\amygo_python\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\tokens.py", line 19, in **contains**
return item is not None and (self is item or item[:len(self)] == self)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\theri\Desktop\Python_Amygo\amygo_python\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 76, in fetchone
return self.result.next()
File "C:\Users\theri\Desktop\Python_Amygo\amygo_python\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 797, in **next**
result = next(self._result_generator)
File "C:\Users\theri\Desktop\Python_Amygo\amygo_python\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 830, in **iter**
raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

```
    Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT %(0)s AS "a" FROM "accounts_account" WHERE "accounts_account"."id" = %(1)s LIMIT 1
```

Params: (1, 1)
Version: 1.3.6
Sub SQL: None
FAILED SQL: None
Params: None
Version: None

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\theri\Desktop\Python_Amygo\amygo_python\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\theri\Desktop\Python_Amygo\amygo_python\venv\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 81, in fetchone
raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

I am using the following versions:
django-4.1 , djongo-1.3.6 , pymongo-4.2.0 , sqlparse-0.2.4

Comment: please use code not images of code/errors

Comment: what's your version of django?

Comment: I am using the following versions:   django-4.1 , djongo-1.3.6 , pymongo-4.2.0 , sqlparse-0.2.4

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue Downgrading django from 4.1 to 3.2 worked for me.

`pip install django==3.2`

Comment: This version worked for me and resolved the issue

Comment: For me downgrading worked also to django==4.0